# Why is Chandra Grahan (Lunar eclipse) considered unsafe for pregnant women in Hinduism?

Tags: rituals, women, eclipse

It is said that women should not work during Lunar Eclipse or *Chandra Grahan*. It is said that doing so effects the physical health of the baby.

Is there any mention of this in the scriptures, or any specific reason behind this ritual?

Comment: kindly refrain from asking scientific reasons here

Comment: Yes, people should only post questions where the answers cannot be disproved by science. Asking for reason and evidence is against religion. You just have to take it on faith. /sarcasm

Comment: See related one here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2864/what-is-the-significance-of-visiting-temple-on-amavasya-day/2871#2871

Comment: My question was, is it related to anything scientific as hindu culture normally has many things which are related to science very easily and not to portray any different idea

Comment: Hello and welcome to Hinduism.SE. Asking for a scientific reason is considered off-topic on this site. For more information, you can refer this [meta post](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/142/124). Please edit your question accordingly. Will close as of now.

Comment: Please don't feel sorry for posting an offtopic question. Go through meta to get idea on how a question should be. BTW, no one will decide your Character with the way your posts are.. :)

Comment: I have improved the question and voted to reopen. I think this has scope of a good answer, let's see if we can have any good answer to this.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the thoughts during the sexual union for conceiving a child & later during the pregnancy, are important for the mental & physical healths of that child.
From [Garbha Upanishada](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/tmu/tmu18.htm):

> Action corresponds to the mental state (of the actor). Hence the child (born) takes after (the thought of) the parents. From parents with minds full of anxieties (at the time of union) are born the blind, the lame, the hunchback, the dwarf, and the limbless. **(From impregnation) during the eclipses of the sun and the moon, children are born with defective limbs.** Increase or decrease, similarities or dissimilarities of bodies arise (in children) through the **influence of time, place, action, ḍravya (substance), and enjoyment**. From a well-conducted intercourse (or union), the child being born with the form of the father possesses, his qualities, just as the image in a glass reflects truly the original.

Hence the state of "impregnation" as described above, also could be extended to the state of "pregnancy".

Comment: thanks, is it possible to approximately date this particular Upnishada?

Comment: @user13107, it's not easy to find the date of this Upanishada. There are various links in its [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbha_Upanishad). We might have to do some research to be able to reach to the ancientness of it.

Comment: I referred to `Patrick Olivelle (2014), The Early Upanisads` page 8-9. it said time of individual upnishads is given in https://www.amazon.com/Samnyasa-Quellenstudien-Hinduismus-Abhandlungen-Morgenlandes/dp/3515019057 but it's in german and book not available on the internet also. let me know if you find this/another souce

Comment: @user13107, thanks for awarding bounty. However, I am not sure if this Qn was worth a bounty of 100. I tried to find an answer by you to return it back. But couldn't. If you write in future, I would be happy to give it back. :-)